# Joining fields in Processing Modeler of QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I am trying to join field district layer with output A .

How can I do this?

I added Vector field input but i cannot see the output A field to make the join by fields .

I have attached an image to illustrate this case.

[image]